# Mapping between a type and string and vice-versa in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm having a little bit of a difficult time solving this problem for some reason. I have some types like `BlogPost` or `Page`, and they need to map to their own string IDs `'blog-post'` or `'page'`. The obvious solution is to include a `type` field:

```js
interface Document {
    type: string,
}


type BlogPost = {
    type: 'blog-post',
    title: string,
}

type Page = {
    type: 'page',
    // ...
}
```

Ok, but now we have some generic interface and we need access to that type! So, maybe we can define a utility type like:

```js
type DocumentType<T extends Document> = T['type'];
```

Great, now `DocumentType<BlogPost> = 'blog-post'`… but it's `'blog-post'` in a *type* sense. I can't just do like:

```js
const type: string = DocumentType<BlogPost>;
```

So how do we… extract this type? How do we get this data out, without doing something ridiculously manual like:

```js
function GetType<T extends BlogPost>(): string {
    return 'blog-post';
}
```

cause that's annoying for obvious reasons.

Ideally it would be best to just skip that `type` field at all! And do instead something like this:

```js
type DocumentTypes = {
    'blog-post': BlogPost,
    'page': Page,
}
```

Which is cool cause then we can pull the reverse!

```js
type DocumentFromType<S extends keyof DocumentTypes> = DocumentTypes[S];

// DocumentFromType<'blog-post'> === BlogPost
```

But… I can't seem to figure out how to go the other way around!

Any thoughts? Thanks,

**Edit** here’s the use case:

The reason is because the API im using requires string types, ie query ‘document.type’ == ‘blog-post’. I would like to `Query<BlogPost>().all()` hence we must convert the type BlogPost to the string blog-post.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details on an actual use case, because I'm struggling to find one?

You can't create a "mapping" between a type and a value. There needs to be an actual object or a function which maps one value to another.

Comment: The reason is because the API im using requires string types, ie query ‘document.type’ == ‘blog-post’. I would like to `Query<BlogPost>().all()` hence we must convert the type BlogPost to the string blog-post.

Comment: I assume you come from a C# or similar statically typed language background. In those languages, a type is an actual object (C# example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=net-5.0). This means a generic parameter is an actual "parameter" of a function which you can use. Example:
`public static string Query<T>() => typeof(T).FullName;`
That is not the case in Typescript - you won't be able to get an object from type.

Comment: Your best bet is something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-faraday-vimxc?file=/src/index.ts)
`query<BlogPost>("blog-post")`
Good thing about this is that intellisense will be triggered once you type in `query<BlogPost>(` so you won't need to fill in the value manually.

Comment: In your case it also might be worth looking into an [enum example](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-water-nbife?file=/src/index.ts)

Comment: @AleksandrŠmailov I do not, actually, I come from Rust, C++, and Haskell! I was hoping typescript would be a little bit… *cooler*.

Comment: In my opinion, it is pretty cool :) I do understand how such a feature might be missed, however, once you understand the purpose of Typescript it all makes sense.
To sum it up: Typescript is only there to generate "javascript" while having cool static type checking in the source code. Since you can't have types in the "javascript" you can't have logic based on types in the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something similar, but then you need to define all allowed entity types in one place, like tuple.

```js
interface Document {
    type: string,
}

type Base = { type: string };

type BlogPost = Base & {
    type: 'blog-post',
    title: string,
}

type Page = Base & {
    type: 'page',
    // ...
}

type MyTypes = [
    BlogPost,
    Page
]

type Iterate<T extends Base[], Result extends Record<string, Base> = {}> =
    (T extends []
        ? Result
        : (T extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
            ? (Tail extends Base[]
                ? (Head extends Base
                    ? Iterate<Tail, Result & Record<Head['type'], Head>>
                    : never)
                : never)
            : never)
    )

type DocumentTypes = Iterate<MyTypes>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsEFcC2FzIDeAUMmcmAJ4AOEAXMgM5hSgDmANMQL7HFW1kAITiMUAXiIUa9Ji3bJuAbj4CUQgDbo2ABXTNkkkWOQAyIqXJqGAcgBGWtgFpq%20sDa7kKwMBtnNWEE4eVRlkHTg2CWFRFHMSL2tkG2pIiA9LMgB6LOQAOgKQ-jCAWUoAFRlGQ2QAbUzhRz1mT3IIqOIAXVDBAElIKDhIAB5y5AgAD0gQABNq4whazo5kACUIRiwNMHGp-Dm1iAR0KBnhgPYVhYA%20GsJuW-EGgAoxyemDpYavAH5Dze233IDFeuw%201VqoBg0GQAAkIHAZisCnkoTDynBgBpul5ceQ-q9MRowft5rEvnjKfjkM94YiSbMyWIgVS8X9%20tAhhBRkSVusATtzOtjqdhnSZrUbGobMs4QiZtdrizWV4GCAIAA3aAASmVVLVmp1euByHVWqguq8uuKggw2Dw4EqtGqkg5gxGZSdG2uQA)

**UPDATE**

A bit readable way:

```js
interface Document {
    type: string,
}

type Base = { type: string };

type BlogPost = Base & {
    type: 'blog-post',
    title: string,
}

type Page = Base & {
    type: 'page',
    // ...
}

type MyTypes = [
    BlogPost,
    Page
]



type Rename<T extends Base[], Prop> =
    (Prop extends keyof T
        ? (T[Prop] extends { type: infer Type }
            ? Type & string
            : never)
        : never)

type Iterate<T extends Base[]> =
    {
        [Prop in keyof T as Rename<T, Prop>]: T[Extract<Prop, string>]
    }

type DocumentTypes = Iterate<MyTypes>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsEFcC2FzIDeAUMmcmAJ4AOEAXMgM5hSgDmANMQL7HFW1kAITiMUAXiIUa9Ji3bJuAbj4CUQgDbo2ABXTNkkkWOQAyIqXJqGAcgBGWtgFpq%20sDa7kKwMBtnNWEE4eVRlkHTg2CWFRFHMSL2tkG2pIiA9LMgB6LOQAOgKQ-jCAWUoAFRlGQ2QAbUzhRz1mT3IIqOIAXT5QwQAlfDg8AB5y5AgAD0gQABNq4whazo5wqHRqAD5DBoAKHTXqcan8OeQAawhKdBhkcoavAH5kHfLa-fXOo%20nTwmlaBlAMGgtzCvC84PIT0qgnMAXY9whyAYIAgADdoABKBFkZFozG9FAASUgUDgkFGXxO81iSy24gaCURbwOyFA50u11uyFEyAGICGEFGK3em06DFeAFEpqSEGBhiKVnCghtul5eMVBBhsHhwNCINVJMToGTBWU9YwNkA)

Comment: Oh dear, the complexity of that is a code smell. I suppose I'll have to come up with something else.

Comment: @ThorCorreia I made an update